# Weird Java variable declaration

Tags: java, variables, methods

I came across some code and saw a very weird way of declaring a variable

```
double var1 ();
```

Has anyone come across java code written in this manner? I am not sure what this actually does, the thing that confuses me and is new to me is the space between the variable name and "()".

Surrounding Code:

```
void setVar1 (double Var1);
double var1 ();
```

I actually think this maybe a method declaration actually instead of a variable declaration. Opinion?

Comment: Please give us some context; where did you see this?

Comment: Can you post the surrounding context?

Comment: no, it is written like that. It is a part of unit testing code.

Comment: Is it inside an interface?

Answer (score 4):

The only way that would be valid is if it was a method declaration inside an interface. For example

```
interface What {
    double var1();
}
```

It's not a field.

[Here is the official Java tutorial on interfaces.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)

> the thing that confuses me and is new to me is the space between the
>   variable name and "()".

Whitespace characters are delimiters between Java syntax elements. You can put as many such spaces as you want

```
interface What {
    double var1                                                 ();
}
```

or even

```
interface What {
    double var1  




                                  ();
}
```

Comment: It could also be prefixed with `abstract` and be an abstract method declaration in an abstract class.

Comment: @HotLicks - true, but if that were the case, the OP probably would have guessed what it was.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when you do method declaration in an interface